# jquery onload not working (jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile `$(window).load(function () {});` not working.
I dont work by mvc.. I pass the page name in the address and load it from the index so the link is like --> index.php?option=com_pages&page=signup signup is the page's name.

Jquery onload is working well on the desktop website version although I pass the page's name by the same style.

here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
      alert("yaaaaa");
        var curr = new Date().getFullYear();
        var opt =
        {

        }

        opt.date = {preset : 'date'};
        opt.datetime = { preset : 'datetime', minDate: new Date(2012,3,10,9,22), maxDate: new Date(2014,7,30,15,44), stepMinute: 5  };
        opt.time = {preset : 'time'};


        $('select.changes').bind('change', function() {
            //var demo = $('#demo').val();
            var demo = "date";
            $(".demos").hide();
            if (!($("#demo_"+demo).length))
                demo = 'default';

            //$0("#demo_" + demo).show();
            $("#demo_default").show();
            //$('#test_'+demo).val('').scroller('destroy').scroller($.extend(opt[$('#demo').val()], { theme: $('#theme').val(), mode: $('#mode').val(), display: $('#display').val(), lang: $('#language').val() }));
            //$('#test_'+demo).val('').scroller('destroy').scroller($.extend(opt["date"], { theme: "jqm", mode: "scroller", display: "modal", lang: "" }));
            $('#test_default').val('').scroller('destroy').scroller($.extend(opt["date"], { theme: "jqm", mode: "scroller", display: "modal", lang: "" }));
        });

        $('#fac').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

the alert works only when refreshing the page not when I go to the page from another one by a link

Comment: Try with $(document).on('pageinit', function () { }); for jquery mobile

Comment: working with refresh only too